# My objects/planes aren't selectable anymore

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, error

Firstly i apologize if this has been answered over and over again, but i've recently gotten into blender in the past week so i'm still new to everything, but when i opened my blender file that i've been working on; my objects/planes aren't selectable at all.
I'm able to select the cube, but not my bigger plane/object i've been working on.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are in Edit Mode. Press Tab to leave Edit Mode and return to Object Mode.